# Advantage of lateinit over null initialization in java?

Tags: java, kotlin

I was trying some Android stuff and learning Kotlin on the way and I was wondering how to initialize Views and properties in general.

As far as I understand, the contracts in Kotlin and Java ("I will initialize before use") and both UninitializedPropertyAccessException and NullPointerException are more or less equivalent. You can do a isInitialized check in both cases. I just don't know why JetBrains would bother with null-safety so much and then introduce the exact same thing in a different shape.

So, is there any advantage in lateinit?

Example Code:

```java
public class Foo {
    private String bar = null;

    public void bar123() {
        if (bar == null) {
            bar = "bar";
        }
    }
}
```

vs

```kotlin
class Foo {
    private lateinit var bar: String

    fun bar123() {
        if (!::bar.isInitialized) {
            bar = "bar"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The advantage is that since `var bar` is declared as `String` and not `String?` you don't need to perform null-checks and therefore your code (that refers to `bar`) is cleaner

Comment: But in my opinion, if (!::bar.isInitialized) is pretty much the same as a null check. I can't see where the Kotlin version is cleaner.

Comment: @Anonymous, i did mean additional null checks outside the init code (constructor/builder/etc). You avoid doing all those `!!` where receiver expects `String` while you pass `String?`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko Okay, avoiding null outside of the class makes totally sense to me. Just tried to return an uninitialized property and got an exception. Do you want to submit that one as an answer? Then I can mark the question as solved.

Comment: @Ano.Nymous you can never set it to null again, once it is initialized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to make compiler aware that the property is non-nullable though it will be initialized later. That would reduce null-checks on this property in the receiver code.

```kotlin
class Foo {
    lateinit var prop: String
}

class Bar {
    var prop: String? = null
}

fun consumeNotNull(arg: String) {
    println(arg)
}

fun main() {
    val foo = Foo()
    consumeNotNull(foo.prop) // OK

    val bar = Bar()
    consumeNotNull(bar.prop) // Error: Type mismatch: inferred type is String? but String was expected
    consumeNotNull(bar.prop!!) // OK
}
```

Imagine that `bar.prop` is referred to in N places. Then in each place you have to "scream" at it (`bar.prop!!`) to make compiler happy. `lateinit` mechanism lets you to to avoid that and be more "quiet" :) *(and keep your code cleaner)*

Of course, if `Foo::prop` isn't initialized by the moment of using it in runtime, you will get exception:

> UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property prop has not been initialized

but in compare to NullPointerException it's bit more descriptive.

Comment: Is that the only use case of ```lateinit```  ?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Nikolai Shevchenko's answer: even inside the class I'd consider `isInitialized` a likely indicator that a nullable property can be more useful.

The primary use-case for `lateinit` is when you can't initialize a property in the constructor but *can* guarantee that it's initialized "early enough" in some sense that most uses won't need an `isInitialized` check. E.g. because some framework calls a method initializing it immediately after construction.

In fact, originally there was no `isInitialized`; it only appeared [in Kotlin 1.2](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html), and `lateinit` was already in 1.0 (I believe).

Answer (score 2):

One another use of a lateinit variable is that once it is initialized you can never make it uninitialized, "So one check will make it sure that it is never gotta be a null or changed by any other Thread".

```kotlin
class Foo {
    lateinit var prop: String
}

class Bar {
    var prop: String? = null
}

fun main() {
    val foo = Foo()
    foo.prop = "Hello"
    // You can never make it uninitialized now, you can only change it.
    // A single isInitialized is ok. (Rather than checking everytime, because it can be null again)

    val bar = Bar()
    bar.prop = "String"
    println(bar.prop!!)
    bar.prop = null
    println(bar.prop!!) // KotlinNullPointerException, check everytime you use it with ?. operator
    // Call when not null: bar.prop?.let { println(it) }
}
```